# Using composer to replace MVC Framework

Tags: php, frameworks, composer-php

i'm building a new project on top of CodeIgniter MVC framework, but now that i'm looking at the design, i will actually not use most of the framework features except for 1.form validation, 2.router and 3.session/cookie/input handling, and 4.views generation

even for database i will use [Redbeans php ORM](http://redbeanphp.com/).

So my question

1. how can i glue these components that i fetched with composer from other frameworks so i can inject them into my project and be good to go without other extra stuff that i don't need ?
2. would it be a wise decision ? or is there any risks of depending on components rather than whole framework ?

i have googled a lot but it seems like i'm using the wrong keywords or something, i could not find any tutorial except for [this one](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1) -which dictate symphony- that teach you how to do this and what are the risks of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep from digressing, I'm simply going to answer your two main questions:

1) There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to use composer to grab your packages, so I wont do a full writeup, but basically what you need to do is download composer, create a composer.json file, then run composer to have it download all those packages and their dependancies. All you then need to do is in one of the already loaded codeigniter files, autoload the autoload.php file

```
`require 'vendor/autoload.php';`
```

Check the composer documentation [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) on how to download composer and setup your json file.

2) Definitely. The Laravel framework is actually built this way under the hood, instead of writing everything themselves, they use composer to pull in packages from other projects like Symfony to do certain tasks.

Comment: thanks, my intentions and my question was to drop CI and only depends on Composer packages to substitute the components that i need from CI. was hoping for a simple suggestion on how to glue these components together (how to build my own front controller)

Comment: in that case, perhaps look at http://www.slimframework.com/ and use that as your raw base, and add in the packages you need. Rather than starting completely from scratch. If you want to start from stratch, Fabiens article that you linked to shows the approach, even if it is symfony heavy

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) to explore which components Composer offers, RedBeanDB is definitely in there. However, in contrast to Symfony, CodeIgniter is not really Composer-friendly. So if you are looking for a proper way to just load these few CodeIgniter components as a dependency, I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: would you care to suggest how to glue them all together in my front controller ?